# std::map::iterator references non-existing object?

Tags: c++, stl

Considering the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        int someInt;
        MyClass() : someInt(666) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int,MyClass> myMap;
    std::map<int,MyClass>::iterator it = myMap.end();
    const MyClass& ref = it->second;
    std::cout << ref.someInt << std::endl;
}
```

Since the map is empty and `it = myMap.end()`, what Object does `it->second` reference? Is this an invalid reference because `it = myMap.end()`?

`map<int,MyClass>` does not create an instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what Object does `it->second` reference? Is this an invalid reference because `it = myMap.end()`?

Indeed. `myMap.end()` is a valid iterator but it must not be dereferenced. `it->second` attempts to do exactly that and causes undefined behaviour.

> `map<int,MyClass>` does not create an instance of MyClass.

True, but irrelevant. `myMap.end()` will always – no matter the content of `myMap` – contain a reference to a “one past end” iterator which must never be dereferenced.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes completely sense to me. What confuses me then, is the fact, that it seems that the STL "uses" invalid references. As far as i know, the C++ Standard does not define any kind of "null reference". In a well-behaved program there should not be any references that reference non existing objects (or NULL). Is this iterator behavior conforming to the C++ Standard?

Comment: @DyingSoul In a word, no, it’s not bad style. End iterators are an example of a software pattern known as “[sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)”. The only problem is that C++ (for performance reasons) does not check for illegal accesses. The sentinel is a completely valid object, you can assign it, compare it …. But it’s invalid to dereference it. Ideally, the compiler would guard against attempts to do this but unfortunately it cannot, since it doesn’t know whether a given iterator is valid.

Comment: Thanks :-), i see the main point and i can absolutely live with that. I will never dereference the end iterator. The only thing the confuses me is the fact, that the end pointer holds an invalid reference (second) on purpose. Suppose, i am writing my custom type of iterator. When i set up the end iterator, then i have to initialize the reference "second". Since the end iterator does not stand for an existing object, i have to do something like: ValueType& second = *rand() or ValueType& second = *NULL which both violates the C++ Standard. How is this done in the STL?

Comment: @DyingSoul “When i set up the end iterator, then i have to initialize the reference "second".” – No, you don’t have to do that. Your *iterator* will be initialised to some value, but not the object that it is referring to. In the simplest case, when the iterator is a pointer, then that pointer will be initialised (e.g. to 0 or any other address) but the pointee will not.

Comment: @DyingSoul: the end iterator does not hold an invalid reference; it most likely holds a null pointer. You can write invalid code that creates an invalid reference from it (by dereferencing the null pointer), but the iterator itself won't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers and sorry for my rigidity :-(. I have this iterator class and the class has this member "second" which is a reference to the value type of the container. Because it is a reference it has to be initialized to reference an object. If the iterator does not point to valid object (like the end iterator) then i have no other choice than creating an invalid reference.

Comment: @DyingSoul Your iterator should have no member named “second”. You are seemingly mixing iterators with data. Better ask a new question. Explaining in comments isn’t really possible.

Comment: OH F... !!! Thank you very much! The "second" is not a member of iterator. It is a member of the "value" type which is actually *not* the Value from the <Key,Value> template arguments of the container but just the std::pair<Key,Value>. Sorry, i was stupid with that!

Answer (score 1):

[std::map::end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/end/) returns the iterator to the first element after the last element in the map. If you try to dereference it, you will invoke an undefined behaviour (google for "C nasal demons")

Answer (score 0):

`.end()` on an STL container points to *one past the end* of the contained sequence. The iterator is only valid for comparison.

Under the hood it's a pointer, which you obviously *can* compare, but which might point to unmapped memory.

Answer (score 0):

That is undefined behaviour, it could do nothing or it could give you a segment violation